# Model binding with objects using [FromRoute] and [FromQuery] in .net core 3.1 returns null

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-core-3.1

I have tried to hit the action method with this url in the postman and it's not reading the value for
employeeNumber from [FromRoute]
Postman request: https://localhost:44309/Department/9002069554

```
[HttpGet("{employeeNumber}", Name = "Get")]  
public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromRoute] Employee employeeNumber)
    {
        //
    }
public class Employee
{
    [BindRequired]
    [FromRoute]
    public string employeeNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accept parameter can't be same as the property name, you should change it.

```
[HttpGet("{employeeNumber}", Name = "Get")]  
public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromRoute] Employee employee)
{
    //
}
```

Comment: Hi @JSNS, if it works, you can mark it as answer, this will help others with similar problems to find a solution more easier, thanks :)